# Contar total de valores iguales

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas:

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  label VARCHAR( 255 )
);

CREATE TABLE addresses(
  cityid INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY( cityid ) REFERENCES cities( id )
);
```

Me piden que obtenga el listado de total de empleados por ciudad. Con esto

```
select label from cities c inner join addresses a where c.id = a.cityid order by c.label;
```

obtengo un listado de ciudades, en el que cada ciudad aparece repetida tantas veces como empleados vivan en ella. Pero no consigo lo que busco, un listado en el que aparezca la ciudad y el número de veces que se repite en la consulta anterior (que equivale al número de empleados que viven en ella).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Únicamente es necesario añadir un `count` en el `select` y agrupar por ciudad, de ese modo obtienes los registros por ciudad.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
  id INTEGER ,
  label VARCHAR( 255 )
);

CREATE TABLE addresses(
  cityid INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO cities (id,label) VALUES (1,'Madrid'),(2,'Tokio'),(3,'París');

INSERT INTO addresses (cityid) VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select label, count(*) AS total from cities c inner join addresses a where c.id = a.cityid group by c.label order by c.label;

| label  | total |
| ------ | ----- |
| Madrid | 4     |
| París  | 1     |
| Tokio  | 2     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)